# Getting a dictionary by ref

Tags: c#

I was wondering if a right value of a dictionary can be by ref.
so, when i'm changing the value of the dictionary some other value will also will change
for example:

```
double num = 7;
Dictionary<string,double> myDict = new Dictionary<string, double>();
myDict.Add("first",num);
myDict["first"]=4;
// i want num also to change to 4.. is it possible?
```

thank you for any help.

Comment: nope, this impossible for `double`

Comment: the latest value of first is 4.0 in your Dictionary what you want?

Comment: As far as I'm aware you can't with value types, but you could wrap your variable `num` in a class to make it a reference type.

Comment: i want the variable num to be changed to 4 as well...
maybe if i will use class Double? 
impossible?

Comment: @DhavalPatel: The OP wants that `4.0` reflected in the *variable* originally passed to the `Add` method, as if not the value of that variable were stored in the dictionary, but actually a reference to the variable itself.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper:Thanks ha ha that's not possible double is value type it's not a ref type

Comment: @DhavalPatel: I wouldn't say this basically hinges on whether the dictionary values are of a value type or a reference type. If you exchange `double` in the example above with a reference type like an array, that does not change anything about the question. Only the workaround presented by [`Jon`](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) in his answer works, yet it still requires that a wrapper object is instantiated and added at first, while later changes do not directly change the wrapper object, but only one of its members. This may or may not be suitable for the situation of the OP.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, that's basically not possible. If you want something like that, you'd need a wrapper class type, e.g.

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could use:

```
var wrapper = new Wrapper<double> { Value = 7.0 };
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Wrapper<double>>();
dictionary.Add("first", wrapper);
dictionary["first"].Value = 4;
Console.WriteLine(wrapper.Value); // 4.0
```